# C# XmlWriter and invalid UTF8 characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml, utf-8

We created a unit test that uses the following methods to generate random UTF8 text:

```
        private static Random _rand = new Random(Environment.TickCount);

        public static byte CreateByte()
        {
            return (byte)_rand.Next(byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue + 1);
        }

        public static byte[] CreateByteArray(int length)
        {
            return Repeat(CreateByte, length).ToArray();
        }

        public static string CreateUtf8String(int length)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(CreateByteArray(length));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(Func<T> func, int count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                yield return func();
            }
        }
```

In sending the random UTF8 strings to our business logic, XmlWriter writes the generated string and can fail with the error:

```
Test method UnitTest.Utf8 threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x0E, is an invalid character.

System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Byte* pDst, Boolean entitize)
System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteAttributeTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriterIndent.WriteString(String text)
System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(String localName, String value)
```

We want to support any possible string to be passed in, and need these invalid characters escaped somehow.

XmlWriter already escapes things like &, <, >, etc., how can we deal with other invalid characters such as control characters, etc?

PS - let me know if our UTF8 generator is flawed (I'm already seeing where I shouldn't let it generate '\0')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [XmlConvert Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx) has a lot of useful methods (like EncodeName, IsXmlChar, ...) for making sure you're building valid Xml.

Comment: I think I could check IsXmlChar on my random byte generator, and retry if it fails.  I think this is a pretty good solution.  We are not too worried about performance, since this is unit testing.

Comment: In using random characters with a test suite, it can make it hard to recreate a failed test, since your tests are non-deterministic.

Comment: That is why we review the Debug output of failed tests.  Our Debug output is very extensive.  We merely take the failed input and make a specific test for that input.

Answer (score 7):

There are two problems:

1. Not all characters are valid for XML, even escaped. For XML 1.0, the only characters with a Unicode codepoint value of less than 0x0020 that are valid are `TAB` (`&#9;`), `LF` (`&#10;`), and `CR` (`&#13;`). See [XML 1.0, Section 2.2, Characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets) .

   For XML 1.1, which relatively few systems support, any character except `NUL` can be escaped in this manner.
2. Not all sequences of bytes are valid for UTF-8.  For example, according to the [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt), "The octet values C0, C1, F5 to FF never appear." Probably you would be better off just creating `String`s of characters and ignoring UTF-8, or creating the `String`, converting it to UTF-8 and back if you're really into encoding.

Answer (score 6):

Your UTF-8 generator appears to be flawed. There are many byte sequences which are invalid UTF-8 encodings.

A better way to generate *valid* random UTF-8 encodings is to generate random characters, put them into a string and then encode the string to UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

Mark points out that not every byte sequence is a valid UTF-8 sequence.

I'd like to add that not every character can exist in an XML document. Only [some characters are valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets), and this is true even if they are encoded as a [numeric character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-charref).

**Update:** If you want to encode arbitrary binary data in XML, then use Base64 or some other encoding before writing them to XML.